# Are antique stock certificates that are endorsed/signed on the back automatically "bearer certificates" and of value without proof of ownership?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, share-certificate

I have spent hours researching this topic, with no luck.  My father (a retired antique dealer) has tasked me with figuring out whether a collection of old stock certificates have any negotiable value.

But before I research the individual certificates, I need to know whether he could even legally claim any possible $ the stocks might be worth.  According to pretty much every source I’ve read, you need proof of ownership or family connection to claim and endorse a certificate.  But from what I can tell all those sources were referring to certificates that were never signed/endorsed by the original owner (which is typically the case when people find old stock certificates).

But what if the person who owned the stock already SIGNED/ENDORESED IT on the back?  That’s the question I can’t find a definitive answer to.  Of the many old stock certificates my father got in various auctions and other lots of old paper and antiques over several decades, a couple dozen were actually endorsed on the back and never canceled.

**Even though he is not a relative of the original (long-deceased) owners, does the fact that the stock certificates are already endorsed make them automatically "bearer certificates," and my father eligible for any funds they might be worth?**

I would really appreciate any help figuring out how to answer this question!

Comment: Not an answer, but just a point of information: My father held some stock certificates of a company that was still around when he died.  I found out that either the company or its transfer agent had long ago sold the stock and given the proceeds to the state's unclaimed property department.

Comment: @Lou That is called "[escheatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escheat)".